# Adding a few steps into any 'steam failed to launch game x' related questions:

Tags: discussion

Seems like a lot of questions about game x failing to launch can be solved by these two simple steps:

1. Verifying game cache integrity
2. deleting ClientRegistry.blob

Is there a way to set it up (or create a generic question/answer) so these steps can be performed?

Its gotten to the point where I feel like it doesn't deserve an answer anymore since its been posted several dozen times all over the place.

[example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79622/how-do-i-resolve-a-load-30000065432-error-message#comment109933_79622)

There can be several ways to deal with this:

1. We can put the relevant steps into the tag blurb
2. Make a generic question with the steps as an answer then close all questions as duplicate unless they state that they've tried the 2 steps already.
3. Something else

Comment: Make it way 2 please

Comment: We've had both [success](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/how-can-i-play-game-x-on-mac-questions) and [failure](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-game-completion-time) with this sort of thing in the past, so I'd advise treading carefully.  It's tough to thread the needle of providing good general advice while keeping it focused enough to be useful.  I don't particularly like the "close as dupe" when questions are clearly different - it overloads the "dupe" close reason in a bad way, IMHO.

Comment: Since this seems to be "asking the asker for more information about what they've tried" - a comment seems the best way to proceed in these situations.  Perhaps a canned comment with links to the Steam FAQ entries for these procedures would be a good idea?

Comment: @agent86 what do you do about questions where those 2 steps will solve the issue then?  Just have duplicate answers to different questions all over the place, or leave them all unanswered with the comment?

Comment: @yx., having the same answer does not make the question a duplicate.  As long as we're answering any sort of technical support type questions, there are going to be problems which are solved by common troubleshooting steps - "did you plug it in?"  "have you tried running a clean build?"  "did you reboot?"  etc.  It's my position that if the questions are unique, it doesn't matter if the answers are similar or the same.

Comment: @agent86 well if you want to propose the canned comment with links as the solution feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible comment that we could leave to request for more information about what the user's already tried:

> Many issues with Steam games can be resolved by [verifying your game cache files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335) or [resetting the ClientRegistry.blob file](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7241-EYON-2343).  Have you tried both of these?  Did either of them help?

... and in Markdown, for your copy/paste pleasure:

`Many issues with Steam games can be resolved by [verifying your game cache files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335) or [resetting the ClientRegistry.blob file](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7241-EYON-2343).  Have you tried both of these?  Did either of them help?`